# Difference between empirical distribution and the data-generating distribution?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, expected-value, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I understand that an empirical distribution is basically sampling from the sample set with replacement. However I am not quite sure how $ \hat{p}_{data} $ and $ p_{data}$ in Maximum likelihood function works and the explanation given in the [Goodfellow book](https://amzn.to/2TxHEHp).

[image]

Comment: Your quote doesn't mention $p_{\text{data}}$, only $\hat{p}_{\text{data}}$. Did you include the correct quotation? What are you unclear about? How does your question and quotation relate do the data-generating distribution?

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the image. In the firs paragraph it says "We can divide by m to obtain the expectation with respect to empirical distribution". This is the part I don't understand. How when you divide by m it becomes empirical distribution?

Comment: Ignoring the complexity of the question I think I can give you a distinction since I understand the term. The empirical distribution is the cumulative distribution described by them sample. The data generated distribution is the underlying distribution that led to the sample. The empirical distribution is necessarily discrete while the underlying or "population" distribution could be continuous or discrete.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thank you so much! I was hoping for such comparision. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This "explanation" is that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log p(x_i;\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\hat{p}_n}[\log p(X;\theta)]$$ 
hence that maximising the likelihood is like minimising the Kullback-Leibler divergence between $\hat{p}_n$ and $p(\cdot;\theta)$:
$$\arg\max_\theta \mathbb{E}_{\hat{p}_n}[\log p(X;\theta)]=
\arg\min_\theta \mathbb{E}_{\hat{p}_n}[\log \{p(X;\theta)/\hat{p}_n(X)\}]$$

Comment: How do you define the Kullback-Leibler divergence between a discrete measure and one that is potentially continuous ? The definitions of $\operatorname{KL}(P||Q)$ I've seen assume either that $P\ll Q$ or that $P$ and $Q$ both have densities with respect to some common measure $\mu$. Of course one might state that $P\ll P+Q$ and $Q\ll P+Q$ but that doesn't seem very useful.